# Yammer embed unable to post on "All Company" feed

Tags: yammer

I am using the embedded yammer feed in an external website and everything had been working fine until a couple of weeks ago.  Most users are no longer able to post anything to the "All Company" feed, though they are able to post in other group feeds.

I am using the embedding example on the "All Company" page

In he header, I am calling the platform_embed.js from yammer:

```
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
```

And at the bottom of the page, I am using the following function:

```
<script> yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "company-name.com",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "all"});
</script>
```

My account is able to enter text and the "Post" button turns blue and allows me to post.  The "Post" button no longer turns blue for anybody else in the company.

If I use the following feedId instead of "all"

```
feedId: 3xxxxxx
```

Everybody is able to post to the other groups feeds.

I have tried it both within their network, and on an external network.  I have tried it with the most recent IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera.  If I log in, everything is fine, if the owner of the company logs in, he can't post.

Another odd thing is that when my account is logged in, my profile picture shows up next to the "What are you working on?" input box, and the background behind the company name at the top is now transparent instead of the normal blue.  Nobody else gets those features.

The  code below is identical for both working and non-working user accounts with the exception of the bust value which I'm assuming is the user id or log in token.

```
<iframe id="embed-feed" name="embed-feed" frameborder="none" src="https://www.yammer.com/platform_embed/feed?container=%23yammer-feed&amp;network=companyname.com&amp;feedType=group&amp;feedId=all&amp;network_permalink=companyname.com&amp;bust=1xxxxxxxxxxxx" class="yj-embed-widget yj-embed-feed" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 26px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

However, the embedded html differs between the working and non-working user accounts.

[Allows posting to feedId: "all"]

```
<div id="embedded-feed" class="not-ie">
    <div id="embedFeed" class="yj-embed-widget yj-component">
        <div id="embed" class="yj-embed yj-splightbox yj-embed-wide">
            <div class="yj-hd">
                <h3 style="background-color: transparent; color:#000">
                    companyname.com
                </h3>
                <div class="yj-message-form-container yj-component yam-ui-publisher-embed-publisher" id="yj-embed">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="yj-acc-hidden">Message Composer</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="yj-reply-avatar yj-splightbox-avatar">
                        <a href="https://www.yammer.com/companyname.com/users/matt" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img src="https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/33x33/4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" class="yj-avatar-thumb" alt="Matt McGuire"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="yj-publisher-opener-container">
                        <div class="yj-auto-width-wrapper">
                            <div class="yj-publisher-textarea yj-auto-width-fake-textarea yj-publisher-opener">
                                <a href="javascript://" class="yj-publisher-watermark">What are you working on?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[Does not allow posting to feedId: "all"]

```
<div id="embedded-feed" class="not-ie">
    <div id="embedFeed" class="yj-embed-widget yj-component">
        <div id="embed" class="yj-embed yj-embed-wide">
            <div class="yj-hd">
                <h3 style="background-color: #396B9A; color:#FFFFFF">
                    companyname.com
                </h3>
                <div class="yj-message-form-container yj-component yam-ui-publisher-embed-publisher yj-open" id="yj-embed">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="yj-acc-hidden">Message Composer</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="yj-publisher-opener-container" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="yj-auto-width-wrapper">
                            <div class="yj-publisher-textarea yj-auto-width-fake-textarea yj-publisher-opener">
                                <a href="javascript://" class="yj-publisher-watermark">What are you working on?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The one that works includes the avatar as well as 'yj-splightbox' class in the '#embed' div and the different background colors, and the one that doesn't work includes 'yj-open' class in the '#yj-embed' div.

Again, this all worked up until a couple of weeks ago and I can't find anything in the company's yammer site that specifies who can and can not post to the all company.  Hopefully somebody can help direct me to a solution.  Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: '#embedded-feed'
        , feedType: ''
        , feedId: ''
        , config: {
               header: true
             , footer: true
        }
    });

Comment: When I leave the feedType and feedId attributes blank, the users are prompted which feed to post to.  Interestingly enough, my account defaults to "All Company" while other users are asked to select a group "Post to (type a group name)..." with a dropdown list.

Also, the config:{header: true, footer: true} didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This embed defaults to posting to the All Company feed, but will also allow the user post to any feed or group.

```
<div id="embedded-my-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script 'type="text/javascript"> yam.connect.embedFeed({  
          container: '#embedded-my-feed'});
</script>
```